# From the receiver's end, how do I make sure that all messages sent using MPI_Isend have been received?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm working on an application in which each processor sends a bunch of messages to some other processors using `MPI_Isend` then receives some unknown number msgs.

In my little sample program (*Code below,)* I have 4 processors sending 4 messages to each of the remaining 3 processors, so each processor is supposed to receive 12 messages.

The problem I'm seeing is that when my machine is happy, my program outputs the following

```
Rank 2 receives 12 msgs; Global count = 48
Rank 1 receives 12 msgs; Global count = 48
Rank 3 receives 12 msgs; Global count = 48
Rank 0 receives 12 msgs; Global count = 48
```

But once in a while, some processors just don't receive enough messages as it's supposed to:

```
Rank 1 receives 9 msgs; Global count = 37
Rank 3 receives 12 msgs; Global count = 37
Rank 2 receives 4 msgs; Global count = 37
Rank 0 receives 12 msgs; Global count = 37
```

I know the problem could be with the `while-loop` in which I use `MPI_Iprobe` to check for incoming messages and exit the loop as soon as the check returns false.
But I don't know how I can do this differently. In other words, how can I make sure that all processors receive all the messages they're supposed to receive by the time they reach the `MPI_Allreduce` statement?

My program looks like this:

```
#include "mpi.h"

#include <stdbool.h>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank, p;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

    //ASSUMPTION: using 4 procs
    //Don't worry about this part.
    //just some stupid way to determine the receivers.
    // Irrelevant to the question.
    int recvs[3];   
    int i = 0, nei = 0; 
    for (; nei < 4; ++nei)
    {
        if (nei != rank)        
        {
            recvs[i] = nei;     
            ++i;        
        }
    }

    //Proc sending msgs to its neighbors.
    //In this case, it's all other procs. (but in my real app, it's almost never the case)
    int TAG = 0;
    int buff[4] = {555, 666, 777, 888};
    int local_counts[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0}; //EDIT 1
    for (nei = 0; nei < 3; ++nei)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        { 
            MPI_Request req;
            MPI_Isend(&buff[i], 1, MPI_INT, recvs[nei], TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);             
            local_counts[recvs[nei]] += 1; //EDIT 1
        }
    }

    //EDIT 1: tell processors how many msgs they're supposed to get
    int global_counts[4];
    int expectedRecvCount;
    MPI_Reduce(local_counts, global_counts, 4, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatter(global_counts, 1, MPI_INT, &expectedRecvCount, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    //Receiving
    int recvCount = 0;      
    MPI_Status status;
    int hasMsg = 0;     
    int num; 
    do  
    {
        MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &hasMsg, &status);             
        if (hasMsg)
        {   
            MPI_Recv(&num, 1, MPI_INT, status.MPI_SOURCE, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            ++recvCount;
            printf("\nRank %d got %d from %d", rank, num, status.MPI_SOURCE);       
        }    
    }
    while (recvCount < expectedRecvCount); //EDIT 1
    //while (hasMsg);

    //Total number msgs received by all procs.
    //Now here's where I see the problem!!!
    MPI_Allreduce(&recvCount, &global_count, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
    printf("\nRank %d receives %d msgs; Global count = %d", rank, recvCount, global_count);

    MPI_Finalize();     
    return 0;
```

}

===========================================

**EDIT 1**

One approach that I can think of is that each processors keep track of the number of messages it sent every other processors. Then after the send operation is done, I'll do an `MPI_Reduce` followed by and `MPI_Scatter` on these message counts. That way each processor will know how many messages it's supposed to receive. (See code)
Can anyone comment on the performance of this approach? Would it potentially and seriously hinder the performance?

Answer (score 2):

From the receiver's end, how do I make sure that all messages sent using MPI_Isend have been received? 
- MPI does not provide that functionality, you can only know that all MPI_Isend operations have been completed.

To rephrase your problem, basically the receiver does not know how many messages the senders will send. But the senders know when they have no more messages to send. So, can you use a message that informs the receiver that from rank n is not going to receive any more messages?

Your code is phasing another problem, how to you ensure that all of the MPI_Isend operations have been completed?

Here is a code based on your example. I did not used the MPI_Iprobe, because there is no computation between your MPI_Iprobe and the if statement. Instead I used MPI_Probe.

The following code, ensures that all of the messages have been send, and a process will stop receiving messages, when its receives a `stopTAG` message, from all the other processes.

```
#include "mpi.h"

#include <stdbool.h>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    //ASSUMPTION: using 4 procs
    //Don't worry about this part.
    //just some stupid way to determine the receivers.
    // Irrelevant to the question.
    int recvs[3];   
    int i = 0, nei = 0; 
    for (; nei < 4; ++nei)
    {
        if (nei != rank)        
        {
            recvs[i] = nei;     
            ++i;        
        }
    }

    //Proc sending msgs to its neighbors.
    //In this case, it's all other procs. (but in my real app, it's almost never the case)
    int TAG = 0;
    int stopTAG = 1;
    int buff[4] = {555, 666, 777, 888};
    MPI_Request req[3*5];
    for (nei = 0; nei < 3; ++nei)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        { 
            MPI_Isend(&buff[i], 1, MPI_INT, recvs[nei], TAG, 
                        MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[nei * 5 + i]);
        }
    }
    for (nei = 0; nei < 3; ++nei) {
        MPI_Isend(NULL, 0, MPI_CHAR, recvs[nei], stopTAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, 
                  &req[nei * 5 + 4]);
    }

    //Receiving
    int recvCount = 0;      
    MPI_Status status;
    int hasMsg = 0;     
    int num; 
    char stopArray[size];
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        stopArray[i] = 0;
    }
    stopArray[rank] = 1;
    char stop;

    int completedSends = 0;

    do  
    {
        MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        if (status.MPI_TAG == TAG)
        {   
            MPI_Recv(&num, 1, MPI_INT, status.MPI_SOURCE, TAG, 
                        MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            ++recvCount;
            printf("Rank %d got %d from %d\n", rank, num, 
                        status.MPI_SOURCE);
        }
        else if (status.MPI_TAG == stopTAG) {
            MPI_Recv(NULL, 0, MPI_CHAR, status.MPI_SOURCE, stopTAG, 
                        MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

            stopArray[status.MPI_SOURCE] = 1;
        }
        stop = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            stop &= stopArray[i];
        }
        if (completedSends < (3*5)) {
            int indx;
            MPI_Status status;
            MPI_Waitany(3*5, req, &indx, &status);
            completedSends++;
        }
    }
    while (!stop && (completedSends <= 15));

    //Total number msgs received by all procs.
    //Now here's where I see the problem!!!
    int global_count;
    MPI_Allreduce(&recvCount, &global_count, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 
                    MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
    printf("\nRank %d receives %d msgs;\nGlobal count = %d\n", rank, 
                recvCount, global_count);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Angelos! I actually thinking of using a message counter. See edit in post.

Comment: The solution from @Angelos is, IMHO, much more elegant than anything involving collective communications. It is important to note that its correctness relies on the fact that MPI maintains message ordering, i.e. the receive with MPI_ANY_TAG is guaranteed to match all the messages tagged as TAG *before* it matches the stopTAG message.